# Hiding Directory in URL with htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-security

I have website1.com setup so that when users visit website1.com they get redirected via a meta tag in an index.html to  website1.com/directory

Then they use the website and go to links such as website1.com/directory/index.html or what ever.  I am trying to hide the "directory" in the link so that users only see website1.com/index.html

I have place the htaccess which is to rewrite the url to website1.com/index.html at  website1.com/directory/.htaccess

I am not doing anything else special and this should be an easy task.  My current exact htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} !^directory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ directory/$1 [L]
```

Should be easy right.....  All I get is a 404

In my server I have Mod_Rewrite & mod security and suspect one of them is causing this not to work but can't imagine why.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your rule is incorrect since `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable has starting `/`
2. You need to place this in document root

Use this code in document root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/$1 [L]
```